# Why can you not redirect to files correctly when you swap stdout and stderr by not using Grouping command?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I tried to swap stdout and stderr and redirect each stream to the files, in bash interactive shell.

By using brace Grouping command, I gained the output what I want. But I do not understand why when I do not use Grouping command, the result is not be swapped.

```
$ # Using Grouping command. Swap operation is succeed.
$ { { echo stdout; echo stderr 1>&2; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3; } 1>1.txt 2>2.txt;
$ cat 1.txt
stderr
$ cat 2.txt
stdout

$ # Not using Grouping command. Swap is failed...
$ { echo stdout; echo stderr 1>&2; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 1>1.txt 2>2.txt;
$ cat 1.txt
stdout
$ cat 2.txt
stderr
```

My understanding of the operation of swapping file descriptors with respect to the above command was as follows.

1. `3>&1`: redirect FD3 to FD1 (stdout)
2. `1>&2`: redirect FD1 to FD2 (stderr)
3. `2>&3`: redirect FD2 to FD3 (stdout)
4. `1>1.txt`: redirect FD1 to 1.txt (FD1 points to stderr)
5. `2>2.txt`: redirect FD2 to 2.txt (FD2 points to stdout)

But under my understanding, I think the result should not change depending on whether there are braces or not.

Am I making some basic misunderstandings? Why do the above two command results differ?

Info my env.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash processes file descriptors in reverse order, so from right to left. First `2>2.txt`, then `1>1.txt`, and so on...

Comment: Are there any reference pages? I think this processing order is left to right.

reference: [Bash Reference Manual 3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections)

> The following redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command. Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to right.